# free()-ing a char* stops working after sscanf()"?

Tags: c, memory, malloc, free

I'm having some trouble with some memory issues. The issue is when the line is freed (`free(line)`), there is a

> free(): invalid size error.

From what I know, `sscanf` doesn't modify the string that is passed into it. Weirdly enough, the `free(line)` inside the if statement works fine. I'm not sure what the problem is because I've freed the `char*` like this in other parts of my program without issues, albeit without the sccanf call. Any help would be appreciated.

```
char* line;
read_line(read, &line, 0);
printf("%s\n", line); //gives "playinfoA/30"
char playerLetter[1];
char numberOfPlayers[2];
char temp[1];
if (sscanf(line, "playinfo%1s%1s%s", playerLetter, temp, 
           numberOfPlayers) != 3) {
    free(line);
    return -1;
}
//free(line);
return 0;
```

Comment: `"%1s"` requires an array of length 2, e.g. `char temp[2];`

Comment: Related to @user3386109's comment, `numberOfPlayers[2]` is not large enough to hold `"30"`

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is, free(line) doesn't work when **if** block fails, then you might want to check if **line** is actually pointing to something.

Since you did not initialize **line**, which is a pointer to char, the only other possibility of having it point to some memory location is the call to **read_line**.

Now, I'm not sure what **read_line** does, but try passing **line** instead of **&line** ?